# BASH Script Enter Value into Java Scanner

Tags: java, bash, java.util.scanner, shortcut

I am working on a system where the administrators made life a little difficult. I have a parent script called client.sh. This script calls a Java class, and the Java class has a java.util.Scanner instance that waits for the user to enter a string. It then waits for the user to type in "exit" before exiting.

I want to create a shortcut in my BASH profile to automate this, as I am entering the exact same string every single time into this Java class. So the shortcut would call the client.sh script, print a pre-determined string into the Java prompt, and finally print exit into the Java prompt. How could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds as though you want

```
alias shortcut="(echo exactsamestring; echo exit) | client.sh"
```

Obviously you need to replace `exactsamestring` with the appropriate thing, and `shortcut` with the name of the alias you want to create.

This assumes that `client.sh` just invokes the Java program, and so stdin for `client.sh` will be passed through to the Java program. That's how I read your question, though it's hard to be certain without seeing the script.

Comment: This looks very close. But can I give it a literal string instead of a variable? Additionally, the literal string I want to give it has double quotes in it. This is giving me a headache with the escaping.

I want to give it trace.set("debug",yes)

Comment: @rshaq What I gave you was a literal string. There are no variables in it. If you want double quotes in the literal, then enclose the whole thing in single quotes: `(echo '"exactstring"'; echo exit) ...`

Comment: Turns out it wanted me to escape with

(echo 'trace.set(\"debug\",yes)'; echo exit) ...

Thanks.

Comment: @rshaq yes, it might be that the extra escaping was needed to preserve the quotes as they passed from the script to the Java program.